# AWS SimpleDB sync with Google Calendar

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-calendar-api, amazon-simpledb

Good Day,

I have an app running that currently syncs it's information with AWS SimpleDB. Unfortunately, the person we are developing for has another database that is updated from the web that uses Google Calendar.

I need a way to actually sync Google Calendar with AWS Simple DB. I know the formattings are very different, and I need to know possible solutions.

I am thinking of running an EC2 instance to keep the database up to date but this is a very costly solution.

Opinions would be muhc appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One solution is that- you can export your content in `CSV` file from `Google Calendar` and import that data into `Amazon SimpleDB` or vice-versa.

You can either do it programmatically or can use third party tool. e.g. [SDBExplorer](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/) can help you to export and import your data from Amazon SimpleDB. For `Google Calendar` [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37111?hl=en) is help link.

Disloser: I am the developer of SDBExplorer.

Comment: Great job on the app, it's really useful. Amazon should adopt it or something. Anyway thanks for the advice, but the thing is I can't do it by hand, I need a server/app to do it and not manually

Comment: @user1436508 Yes, in this case you need to write your own code that can export your data from `Amazon SimpleDB` and import your data into `Google Calender`.